# Disable or remove default vim keybinding

Tags: vim, key-mapping, vimrc

Is there a way to disable or remove a default vim keybinding?

For example, if I wanted `<S-k>` (shift-k) to do nothing, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't `unmap` internal keybindings that vim needs but you can map them to `<Nop>` to disable them. Run this command in vim: `:map <S-k> <Nop>` or add this line to you `.vimrc` file:

```
map <S-k> <Nop>
```

Comment: It does not seem to work in vim 8.2.3582 on Windows